# How to write the constructor instead of using Lombok to access public level?

Tags: java, constructor, lombok, access-levels

I changed the access level protected to public but how to write the constructor instead of using Lombok for below code?

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC))
public class abc implements xyz<Event, Void> {

    @NonNull private final Test<Lock<TransactionLock, TransactionLockId>> test;

    ..... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be if there are no other `final` fields defined:

```java
public class abc implements xyz<Event, Void> {

    @NonNull private final Test<Lock<TransactionLock, TransactionLockId>> test;

    public abc(@NotNull Test<Lock<TransactionLock, TransactionLockId>> test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
j
```